# Disintegration theorem: counter-examples in which $\mu_y$ is supported on $\pi^{-1} (y)$ not for $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Recently, I came across Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/254a-lecture-9-ergodicity/#more-252) about disintegration theorem.

> **Disintegration theorem** Let $X$ be a compact metric space, $\mathcal X$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu$ a Borel probability measure on $X$. Let $(Y, \mathcal Y)$ be a measurable space, $\pi:X\to Y$ a measurable map, and $\nu := f_\sharp \mu$ the push-forward of $\mu$ by through $f$. Then there is a collection $(\mu_y)_{y\in Y}$ of Borel probability measures on $X$ with the following properties.
>
> 1. For all bounded measurable map $f:X\to \mathbb C$ and $\nu$-integrable map $g:Y\to \mathbb C$,
>    $$
>    \int_X f (g\circ \pi) \mathrm d\mu = \int_Y \left(\int_X f\mathrm d\mu_y\right)g(y)\mathrm d\nu(y). \quad (\star)
>    $$
> 2. For all bounded measurable map $g:Y\to \mathbb C$, for $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$,
>    $$
>    g\circ \pi = g(y) \quad \mu_y\text{-a.e.} \quad (\star\star)
>    $$

At page 79 of Dellacherie/Meyer's *Probabilities and Potential*, the author said that $\mu_y$ is **not** necessarily supported on $\pi^{-1} (y)$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$. Could you provide a counter-example with the following conditions?

1. $Y$ is a metric space and $\mathcal Y$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
2. it's **not** the case that $\mu_y (\pi^{-1} (y)) = 1$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$.

Thank you so much!

Comment: L. Schwartz, 1973, used the catchy term "image measure catastrophe".  See for example: Fremlin, *Measure Theory* vol. 2 sec. 235.

Comment: Dellacherie and Meyer were not thinking of a counterexample of the form you are asking for. Look at the theorem on that page.